# HTML Video Exporting Using MediaRecorder vs ffmpeg.js

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, mediarecorder

#### TLDR

Imagine I have one video and one image. I want to create another video that overlays the image (e.g. watermark) at the center for 2 seconds in the beginning of the video and export it as the final video. I need to do this on the client-side only. Is it possible to use MediaRecorder + Canvas or should I resort to using ffmpeg.js?

#### Context

I am making a browser-based video editor where the user can upload videos and images and combine them. So far, I implemented this by embedding the video and images inside a canvas element appropriately. The data representation looks somewhat like this:

```js
video: {
  url: 'https://archive.com/video.mp4',
  duration: 34,
},
images: [{
  url: 'https://archive.com/img1.jpg',
  start_time: 0,
  end_time: 2,
  top: 30,
  left: 20,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
}]
```

#### Attempts

1. I play the video and show/hide images in the canvas. Then, I can use the `MediaRecorder` to capture the canvas' stream and export it as a data blob at the end. The final output is as expected, but the problem with this approach is I need to play the video from the beginning to the end for me to capture the stream from the canvas. If the video is 60 seconds, exporting it also takes 60 seconds.

```js
function record(canvas) {
  return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
    const stream = canvas.captureStream();
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    const recordedData = [];

    // Register recorder events
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
      recordedData.push(event.data);
    };
    mediaRecorder.onstop = function (event) {
      var blob = new Blob(recordedData, {
        type: "video/webm",
      });
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      res(url);
    };

    // Start the video and start recording
    videoRef.current.currentTime = 0;
    videoRef.current.addEventListener(
      "play",
      (e) => {
        mediaRecorder.start();
      },
      {
        once: true,
      }
    );
    videoRef.current.addEventListener(
      "ended",
      (e) => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      },
      {
        once: true,
      }
    );
    videoRef.current.play();
  });
}
```

2. I can use [ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/) to encode the video. I haven't tried this method yet as I will have to convert my image representation into ffmpeg args (I wonder how much work that is).

Comment: I don't think you can use ffmpeg.js on client-side. You could make an endpoint that will receive video and image from the client, run ffmpeg on the server and then send the result back to the client